# How to test an 500 - Internal Server Error exception

Tags: java, spring, junit, error-handling, mockito

I need to test if my application throws an exception in case of an 500 error, however I don't know how to simulate that in my code.

I have tried this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class DronefeederApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @SpyBean
  private DroneRepository droneRepository;

  @Captor
  private ArgumentCaptor<Drone> droneCaptor;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    droneRepository.deleteAll();
  }

@WithMockUser(username = "dronefeeder")
  @Test
  @Order(1)
  @DisplayName("1 - Should sabe a new Drone in the DB.")
  void saveDroneTest() throws Exception {

    DroneDto newDroneDto = new DroneDto();

    when(droneRepository.save(any(Drone.class))).thenThrow(new UnexpectedErrorException());

    mockMvc
        .perform(post("/v1/drone").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(newDroneDto)))
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError()
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.error").value("Unexpected Error."));
```

This is the Exception:

```
public class UnexpectedErrorException extends RuntimeException {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public UnexpectedErrorException() {
    super("Unexpected Error.");
  }

}
```

This is the ExceptionHandler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(UnexpectedErrorException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<DataError> handleInternalServer(RuntimeException e) {

    DataError payload = new DataError(e.getMessage());

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(payload);

  }
```

But I get this error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Entity must not be null.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity must not be null.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at
```

I tried the code above but it didnt work.

```
 when(droneRepository.save(any(Drone.class))).thenThrow(new UnexpectedErrorException());
```

Comment: Is the entity that you pass in your production code null by any chance (`droneRepository.save(null)`)?  The DroneDto object that you pass might not be mapped to a Drone object correctly.

Comment: No, its not empty : /

Comment: Does `doThrow(new UnexpectedErrorException()).when(droneRepository).save(any(Drone.class));` work?